# Tiling perlin noise seamlessly

Tags: java, lwjgl, terrain, perlin-noise, procedural-generation

I have been trying to figure out how to create infinite terrain in 3D using perlin noise. I have so far got a terrain that is made of chunks, and when the player moves out of a chunk, new chunks are generated. Chunks out of range are unloaded. So I have the illusion of an infinite world.

I am using perlin noise to create height maps for the chunks (each chunk has its own height map)

My question is how do I seamlessly tile the height map of each chunk so that there aren't horrible gaps in the world between chunks, and without having the same height map for every chunk.

By "gaps in the world" I mean [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKE13.jpg).

And I followed [this](http://devmag.org.za/2009/04/25/perlin-noise/) to implement perlin noise

Here is my perlin noise code:

```
private float[][] perlinNoise(int width, int height, int octave, float[][] whiteNoise)
{
    float[][] result = new float[width][height];

    int samplePeriod = 1 << octave;
    float sampleFrequency = 1.0f / samplePeriod;

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        int x1 = (i / samplePeriod) * samplePeriod;
        int x2 = (x1 + samplePeriod) % width;
        float xBlend = (i - x1) * sampleFrequency;

        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            int y1 = (j / samplePeriod) * samplePeriod;
            int y2 = (y1 + samplePeriod) % height;
            float yBlend = (j - y1) * sampleFrequency;

            float top = (float) MathHelper.interpolateLinear(whiteNoise[x1][y1], whiteNoise[x2][y1], xBlend);

            float bottom = (float) MathHelper.interpolateLinear(whiteNoise[x1][y2], whiteNoise[x2][y2], xBlend);

            result[i][j] = (float) MathHelper.interpolateLinear(top, bottom, yBlend);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public float[][] generatePerlinNoise(int width, int height, Random random, int octaveCount)
{
    float[][] whiteNoise = new float[width][height];
    float[][][] totalNoise = new float[octaveCount][][];
    float[][] perlinNoise = new float[width][height];
    float amplitude = 1.0f;
    float totalAmplitude = 0.0f;
    float persistance = 0.5f;

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            whiteNoise[i][j] = random.nextFloat() % 1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < octaveCount; i++)
    {
        totalNoise[i] = perlinNoise(width, height, i, whiteNoise);
    }
    for (int o = octaveCount - 1; o >= 0; o--)
    {
        amplitude *= persistance;
        totalAmplitude += amplitude;

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                perlinNoise[i][j] += totalNoise[o][i][j] * amplitude;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            perlinNoise[i][j] /= totalAmplitude;
        }
    }
    return perlinNoise;
}
```

Edit: I have just asked about [this on GameDev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/104342/tiling-perlin-noise-seamlessly-but-without-repeating-to-generate-an-infinite-3d) my question there might be more detailed and helpful. **Please try and answer there if possible**, because I will be looking at this post less and that one more.

Edit: I have realised that my noise code is **NOT PERLIN NOISE**. It is actually something called **VALUE NOISE**, which actually doesnt look as good, and wont work for what I need anyway. I cant find any good java implementation of perlin noise. And I dont just want a link to code I can use, I would like to have a tutorial, where I can understand how the algorithm actually works.

Comment: I like your work so far, but is it possible for you to include your relevant portions of code so the community can see potential problem areas in order to assist you?

Comment: Well, the code actually generating the perlin noise is the same as the code from the source I linked. Should I post my code for generating the chunks?

Comment: @ThisClark I put the relevant methods to pastebin

Comment: This is essentially the same as the [generate next chunk with perlin noise](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/93831/generate-next-chunk-with-perlin-noise) question on gamedev.SE

Comment: @Pikalek hmm, how would I modify the perlin noise to return a float as the current vertex height, and have `x and y` as the parameters rather than width and height. Currently it returns a `float[][]` as the whole map.

Comment: Are you using different seed values for each chunk? You shouldn't. Use the same seed value, and if your perlin noise algorithm is correct, it should produce a continuous plane.

Comment: I was using different seed values... It does now tile properly, but every chunk has identical height maps. It doesnt look natural.

Comment: You need to send GLOBAL positions into the noise function, not positions local to the current tile. Like if your tiles are 100x100 verts, when generating verts for tile (1,0) you don't generate data for (0,0)-(100,100) like you did for tile (0,0), you generate (100,0)-(200,100)